# Cocos2d  background music preload

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing an IOS app using cocos2d and the SimpleAudioEngine for playing a background music in different scenes. The problem is that if a preload the background music it plays in the first scene but it is stopped when i turn to a different scene. If I do not preload the background music it is continuously played from one scene to another. 
Any idea?

Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a try( i never used it ).

Instead of using SimpleAudioEngine in your scene , 
Use it in AppDelegate.